# How to define changing dimension objects in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I would like to define an array of blocks and each block will contain an array of nodes of different size. So I wrote a program like the follows, but it won't work. I am wondering how could I do this in FORTRAN? Is there any other better way? The basic difficulties are to make them allocatable!

```
program Mesh
    implicit none
    integer::i

    type node
      double precision::x,y
    end type node

    type block
        integer::NX,NY
        integer::ENB,WNB,SNB,NNB      
        integer::BlockType            
        type(node),dimension(:,:),allocatable::nodes
    end type block

    type(block),dimension(:),allocatable::blocks !Error:Syntax Error in Data Declaration

    allocate(blocks(1:9)) ! here using 9 just to simplify it,error: allocate-object is not               a nonprocedure pointer or allocatable object

    do i=1,sizeof(blocks)
        blocks(i)%NX=i*2  !Here I want to read in some value, but just use i*2 to simplify
        blocks(i)%NY=i*2  !Here I want to read in some value, but just use i*2 to simplify
        allocate(blocks(i)%nodes(0:NX,0:NY)) !error: not allocatable object either
    end do

end program
```

Comment: Your line `type(block)::dimension(:),allocatable::blocks` is syntactically incorrect, so either your code does not compile, or what you have posted is not your code.  To repair this line replace the first occurrence of `::` with `,`.  Oh, and be a bit more specific than just telling us *it won't work*, tell us what errors and messages are generated, that sort of useful diagnostic stuff.

Comment: The syntax error in the line I referred to means that `blocks` is not, when the compiler attempts to process the next line, an allocatable object; the name `blocks` is not associated with anything. Fix that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As High Performance Mark pointed out, fixing syntax where suggested by the compiler will take care of most other error messages. Another place where your compiler is likely to barf is this line:

```
allocate(blocks(i)%nodes(0:NX,0:NY))
```

where `NX` and `NY` are not known outside of a blocks `type`. Please change this line to:

```
allocate(blocks(i)%nodes(0:blocks(i)%NX,0:blocks(i)%NY))
```

Also, I believe you meant to use:

```
do i=1,size(blocks)
```

instead of:

```
do i=1,sizeof(blocks)
```

`sizeof` is a non-standard function that returns the size of the object in bytes. `size` is a standard intrinsic which returns the number of elements in an array. Using `sizeof` in this context may result in a segmentation fault later in the loop or undefined behavior.